# simple java user input, where did i go wrong??

Tags: java

Hi guys im working on a basic java program to get somebodys name, it comes up with a lot of errors could you correct me where i went wrong. Sorry and thanks. I also need to basicly set the user input to a string variable which i can then later store into a text file.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloJello {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Hi using this program i will find out"
            + "what your name is and store it in  document");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your name");  
    name = scanner.next(); // Get what the user types.

}

}
```

Comment: "name" variable's data type??

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: String name = scanner.next();

Comment: Better use scanner.nextLine()

Comment: Use an IDE to find compiler errors quickly!

Answer (score 3):

what is `name` ?

You need to declare the variable reference  properly

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare data type of `name`. It should be a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name="";   // always good to initialize
    System.out.print("Hi using this program i will find out"
            + "what your name is and store it in  document");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name");  
    name = scanner.nextLine(); // Get what the user types. Reads entire line..

}
```